# Map object into array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an object which consists of different key value pairs as below:

```
{1: '20', 2: '2340', 3: '1420', ...., so on} (Not related to any math equation)
```

I want to convert the object keys which are dynamic and have the output something like below:

```
[{"rate_id": '20'}, {"rate_id": '2340'}, {"rate_id": '1420'}, ...., so on}]
```

Any answers or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: can't have multiple properties with same name in a object

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: So what's your question? `I want to replace the object keys [...] Note: I don't want to replace them`..? You can add additional keys if that fits for you

Comment: @Harry You can have `[{rage_id: 20}, {rate_id: 2340}, ...]`

Comment: My bad. Object can't have duplicate keys. Posted on friends behalf. Should have realized this. I will update the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

You should really look at how you make the first object. Looks like it is a array converted to an object. Would be easier to stat with a normal array.

If you can't do anything to change the initial value you can get the values from the object, which will return an array of the values. Then map it to the type you want.

```js
const currentObject = { 1: "20", 2: "2340", 3: "1420" };

// Get values to a array and map them to {rate_id: value}
const rates = Object.values(currentObject).map((value) => ({
  rate_id: value,
}));
// rates will look like this [{ rate_id: "20" }, { rate_id: "2340" }, { rate_id: "1420" }];
```